# Effect of a rotating disk on a grandfather clock

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

The question is as follows: A grandfather clock is placed on a rotating disk. Given the disk rotates once every minute, how long does it take for the clock to be one second out?

Am I correct in thinking that the clock will experience time dilation? Or is the solution more about considering the effect of rotation on the swinging pendulum?

Comment: I suspect the answer would be based on the course you are taking or the book you are drawing from.

Comment: The real question is: did you ask granpa for permission to use his clock in this kind of experiment? :-) Seriously: is the pendulum free to swing in 3D? If yes, then the rotating disk has no effect. In any case relativistic time dilation is negligible at these low speeds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time dilation is going to be utterly negligable.

If I interpret the answer correctly the clock is at the centre of the disk. I would guess you are intended to treat the lowest point of the pendulum swing as exactly over the centre, so the pendulum will swing either side of centre. That means the force on the bob is the restoring force due to gravity minus the centrifugal force caused by the rotation, and this will change the period of the pendulum.

This seems like a fun question. I won't say any more since the site policy forbids giving direct answers to homework questions. I should have given enough hints for you to come up with an answer yourself.

Comment: I follow your logic, and that does seem like the path to follow!

Comment: Note however that a change in a pendulum's rate of ticking due to the centrifugal force acting on the bob has nothing to do with time dilation, it's just a way in which a pendulum fails to behave as an "ideal clock" under certain conditions (an atomic clock would be closer to an ideal clock, and the centrifugal force shouldn't affect it AFAIK). If talfred is interested specifically in time dilation in the inertial frame where the center of the disc is at rest, then the hint I would give is that time dilation in an inertial frame depends only on speed, not on direction or acceleration.